# Show Author information on post page on dashboard

Tags: author, post-editor

When an admin clicks on a post in the WordPress dashboard, is it possible to display the author of the post's details, like meta content? ie. name, phone, email?

Answer (score -1):

When you edit the post (via Admin, Posts), try changing the Options for that screen (dropdown link at the top of the editor page). There is an option there to show Author (and other info) that you might need to enable.

Comment: I just looked it only provides author name in the dropdown.